# Regarding different effect of 'has:purple-***' in Gmail and AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Hi Gmail AppScript Experts,

Suppose we want to search threads in inbox marked 'purple-question'.
The query I wrote was 'in:inbox has:purple-question'.

When I input this in search field of my Gmail, it works and those threads will be displayed.

However, when I use Gmail AppScript, I wrote code like this:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox has:purple-question');
```

yet nothing was returned, which is different from above.

I assue the behavior should be same, however it's not. Does anyone knows why it's like this? Or it's simply a Gmail AppScript bug?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This a long standing issue ([1191](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1191)) that is marked as "won't fix". But this does not really seem like an Apps Script issue, the public [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) does not work with stars either (I have just tested it).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Meanwhile, is there anyway to search those threads marked 'purple-question' since there is limitation on this? I've thought of use webdriver to input query manually and parse the html there, however this is...too heavy...